# How to change maven repository for intelliidea's plugins?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, ubuntu-16.04, intellij-plugin

I'm using Intellij idea **build: IU-171.3780.107** in **Ubuntu 16.04**. I need to use **docker plugin**.

At beginning docker plugin need to download dependencies for *maven central* (http://maven.central.org). I am behind of a proxy and it deny my access to this site

Intellij idea error:
**Failed to download client libraries: Failed to download 'http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/github/docker-java/docker-java/3.0.0/docker-java-3.0.0.jar'**

but i have guaranty access to another maven repository linked to maven central

How i change maven repository address, used by intellij idea for plugins download, to my maven local config in .m2 (setting.xml)

Note: I don't  have problem with dependencies for my own project because it use successfully my setting in .m2 directory, the problem is with a intellij idea plugins.

Comment: I had the same issue but it was because my firewall was blocking the maven site due to Jars being less than 30k.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @papaiatis nop, I put my ide inside a docker image; at home i did install for all necessary plugins. :)